# Google Chrome app keeps disappearing from /Applications

Tags: google-chrome

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Google Chrome several times in the past few weeks. Periodically I run into Chrome just stops working.  I look and .. well .. the Google Chrome app has disappeared. It is no longer in the `/Applications` folder at all.

Why would this happen and what can be done?

**Update**  "Disappeared" means: the directory `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` is no longer there, and Spotlight can no longer find `Google Chrome` or `google` or `chrome` etc.

"Stops working" means: new tabs do not do anything (requested URL just ignored) and immediately give a frowning face as the tab icon.

Comment: Define "just stop working". While you're using it? And you're sure you actually installed the app, and didn't just run it from a disk image that you then deleted? Also, what macOS version are you running?

Comment: Use Spotlight (Cmd + Space) to see if chrome can be located.

Comment: @benwiggy  Yes it stopped working while I was using it.  New tabs do nothing.

Comment: @404NotFound  Not finding in `Spotlight` is the definition (to me) of it having disappeared.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of this 'frowning face' icon? This is very strange. What about the icon in the Dock? If you right-click on that, and select "Options > Show in Finder"?